# Basic logic of Redux

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, redux, react-redux

I have some point that's not clear for me in react-redux and DB.

1. does it make sense to connect my redux store to a DB(Mongo).
   for example: if I have a todo app and I want it to work with redux but updating everything to the DB does it make sense?.
2. If yes(and I believe it is but I'm not sure why) how do I do it I update my store and then the DB by the store or I update the DB and then tell my program to update the store?
3. The real question Is why and HOW to work with redux and a DB together? and is it smart to work with redux and a DB?

Comment: DB is in your backend Redux will be in your frontend app. To connect frontend with backend you need to define a REST API. This will be provide you the needed endpoints to perform the actions you need to manage you app data.

Comment: But after I got my REST API and my redux store with actions that are working how do I connect between them?

Comment: Using the endpoints defined. You can use fetch, axios or whatever library you want to perform the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. It depends on how your app working, for example after some change you can call API and wait to answer, after getting an answer update you redux store, or firstly update your store and show new updated UI to the user, then wait for an answer from the backend(In this case you need revert your changes if you get an error from backend).
3. You need both of them because redux will be reset after you reload your page. You can save all your data in DB to have access to them from every device from where you entered your page.
   Of course, if your data is only one-time usage data (example: searched item name, opened modal, opened dropdown), you don't need to save it in your DB.
   In your redux store, you can have data which comes from DB and data which you will use only in the front end

---

More about Redux you can read in the official website -> [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: thanks, I understood a little bit better so in the answer 2 you are saying that's it better to make the client-side work in a regular way and when x things happen to update the DB. where can I learn this part with the revert changes in case of error from DB?

Comment: For example, you can make an undo-redo system for your app
https://redux.js.org/recipes/implementing-undo-history